# botpress to open chat in new window using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, chatbot

I am making a chat-bot using bot-press. If the user enters keyword "google" I want it to open in new tab. I have tried following code but it gives error.

if(event.text.includes('google')){ window.open('https://www.google.com/search?q=' + event.text )   }

I get this error :- window is not defined

Is it possible?

Comment: Is your code running in a browser or on a Node.js server? If it's the latter – you don't have a `window` object in the backend, that's available in browsers only

Comment: its nodejs server...any possible solution?

Comment: I haven’t worked with botpress. There is probably some way for the bot to send events to the client. The client, which runs in the browser would then open the window in reaction to such an event